# Typescript - keyof on indexed property on generic doesn't properly restrict options

Tags: typescript

Given I have an interface like:

```
export interface IHasIO {
  inputs: {
    [key: string]: string
  },
  outputs: {
    [key: string]: string
  }
}
```

I want to create a function that has that as implementation of that interface as a generic, and ensures that one of the output keys is passed as a param.

So the following type defs would ideally create a function like that:

```
// extract the outputs property by indexing it.
export type Outputs<T extends IHasIO> = T['outputs'];

// only allow a key of one of the outputs to be the function parameter by using keyof.
export type writeToOutput<T extends IHasIO> = (param: keyof Outputs<T>) => void;
```

However, if I create a value that implements that interface, and use it as the generic arg, the param options are not restricted:

```
const instance: IHasIO = {
  inputs: {},
  outputs: {
    a: 'someValue',
    b: 'someOtherVal'
  }
}

// create a dummy fn
const fn: writeToOutput<typeof instance> = (param) => {
}

// this should not work, as `c` is not one of the output keys, but it does work, as it passes the typescript linting errors
fn("c");

// only these should work:
fn("a");
fn("b";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deriving type from Readonly<Array<MyType>> does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74564011/deriving-type-from-readonlyarraymytype-does-not-work-as-expected)

Comment: By explicitly annotating `instance`'s type as `IHasIO` you have told the compiler to forget about anything more specific than that.  You should leave off the annotation and let the compiler infer its type; if you care about ensuring that it's assignable to `IHasIO` you could use the `satisfies` operator in TS4.9+, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mp8lBm).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz yes that seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that by explicitly [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `instance` as `IHasIO`, you have essentially told the compiler that it should not try to keep track of its particular properties; instead it will only know that `instance` is of type `IHasIO`, and thus the `inputs` and `outputs` properties are of type `{[key: string]: string}`, meaning that `keyof typeof instance["outputs"]` is just `string`.  And therefore `fn()` will accept any `string` as input.

If you would like stronger typing, you should just let the compiler *infer* the type of `instance`, by leaving off the annotation.  If you really care about verifying that `instance` is assignable to `IHasIO` without widening it to that type, you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-rc/#satisfies) which will be released in TypeScript 4.9:

```
const instance = {
  inputs: {},
  outputs: {
    a: 'someValue',
    b: 'someOtherVal'
  }
} satisfies IHasIO;
```

But with or without `satisfies`, the type of `instance` is inferred to be

```
/* const instance: {
    inputs: {};
    outputs: {
        a: string;
        b: string;
    };
} */
```

And therefore `keyof typeof instance["outputs"]` is `"a" | "b"`.  And so `fn()` now behaves as desired:

```
fn("c"); // error! 
// ~~~
// Argument of type '"c"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '"a" | "b"'.
fn("a"); // okay
fn("b"); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.9.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQAlMBnfAeTgG8AoORJMAVxhIC5q764BtAa2ABPDiRhRkAcwC6IsZK4BfADRcILZqw61uvAcLijxSabKMTFNBTRoB6G3FBic8GAAs8amBpJwwUCGBoMIJwAEYhyAAmoJKIMAB0NKCQsHDBgXDk6iwkADwAKg4gqEiRPkSkFAB8cAC8cPk8AOSe3k1SANzWdnAQSAA2IZj9-RAA7nCYcHq96L1IHnNuHtmsaRBheMtw6ExI2DAIfb6YUJgAtsCoUGEhTCSxehDoicnQLoIZY+Ko+RBZXhYBSKJTKBGIZHINXqAAowKcLhwnnMAd4ClUAJR1GoANwgCEiXWs2D6ogYokw+zw9W0DG8WmUqlW7E4OkwHCaJAglwAasMmMAmiodKEOVzLuRllA+f0mhYFAZMIcSOgEMByhCKESbAAqOAkpBk5AUqlaLj0ZD06gKLo6Vo5M06NmmSS2p30UUGOTGN30G2WOA6mzWdJ4AAadWmQmeaU+wBjxpglNwPAARPbWKnOnAeqnMKm4AAfOCp0Kp7r2bBQYBKvBTSJMc7nELoJA0A1k1scb4IX7-Va5UMJw1JqnQuBwhHnLG1Gq0Kw0Vsw1PYVMYjo5+xofxQACEcFs9gAfifD3AAIJQCSN4AoWaxjJNFeppqIHxICDwUgPCRITChfotg2M94TOS5rnvUM4CffMixLMsmkSJc8zXDceggPhMEERckGXMt103XpMOwoA)